# PowerBI Embedded - Dynamically create visuals

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need some clarification regarding the creation of Visualizations.  I have a need to create 1 to N number of Visualizations.  Is it possible to dynamically create visuals via code (or some other method) based on some sort of input (I have a need to produce a different number of charts dependant on which client I am viewing the chart from) or am I limited to dragging and dropping on Visualizations onto a report manually at design time?

Ideally I'd like to be able to run some sort of query and then create charts based off this result set. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

*If you're talking about custom visualizations...*
Your best bet is probably to [create a custom visualization](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-custom-visuals-create-for-the-gallery/) that has all the options and features to adapt to varying input.

*If you're talking about reports...*
I don't think generating PowerBI reports with code is really (intended to be) easily done. I recommend trying either creating several different "smart" but hardcoded reports that adapt to the data, and choose between them dynamically, or switching to another technology to do this.